# Illustrator CC: Rename layer shortcut

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

Is there a **shortcut for renaming layers in Illustrator CC?**
There isn't one listed on [Adobe's Default Keyboard Shortcuts](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Comment: Doesn't seem so. I haven't seen such shortcut in any other Adobe product as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hit alt+command+L you will get a new layer below the one you have selected, the advantage is that it displays the layer properties dialog box without having to click on the actual layer.

If you do Command+L then you only get a new layer, no dialog box whatsoever.

I mean, is not the ideal, but it has worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

I have made a free to use script to rename Objects/layers in Illustrator. I have made an action and call this script in that, after that I am assigning a shortcut key to that action. You can see the full documentation, it will be really helpful.
Here's the [Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1h0Mmvda86O2X2_URe47t4p5gRx8dGg05?usp=sharing)

I came across this problem when I was working on a character in Illustrator to be used in an animation. To my surprise, I found that there is no keyboard shortcut in Illustrator to rename layers/objects. With so many groups and layers, renaming things by going in layers panel was very frustrating.